# All windows on the screen at the same time in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

I'm a happy Windows XP user for around 15 years and yesterday I accidentally hit random keys combination which brought me to this

[image]

What's this and how did I do this?

Comment: If you want a fix, can't you just restart?

Comment: Looks like a 3rd party utility to me, never seen anything like that on a standard Windows XP install.

Comment: It looks like a function to easily see all the Windows to find the one you want to jump to. Same remark as Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: I don't think this is an integrated feature of XP. I used it for more than 10 years and never seen that, nor heard that it was possible... it's probably a 3rd part utility meant to provide this function.

Comment: For sure it is another software that you got installed on Win XP. Win XP doesn't have this by default.

Comment: What key combination was it?

Comment: @Ramhound, the problem is that it was a random keyboard combination

Comment: Looks like DExposE2 or TopDesk are possible ways to do this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a guessing game with no actual problem to solve. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/ http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6073/are-guessing-game-type-questions-allowed-on-su

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, I got what I wanted to know that it's not the native functionality

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to duplicate the effect, look to: WinExpose or TopDesk

http://www.otakusoftware.com/topdesk/index.html

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/mac-osx-expose-clone-for-windows-vista/